# await in Nuxt 3 composable blocks page load

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I am creating a project that is using Nuxt 3.
My goal is to create a search page and to properly use composables for them.

**Use-case**
I want to fetch data from an API and use that on my page. I have 2 composables depending on each other, but i cannot make it work with useAysncData without blocking the page from loading first.

**Current code**

```js
# /composables/useContent.ts
export const useContent = () => {
   const items = useState<any>(() => [])
    
   const { data, pending, error, refresh } = useAsyncData(
      'content',
      async () => await $fetch('http://localhost/api/items')
   )
   items.value = data.value ?? []

   return {
     items,
     pending
   }
}

# /composables/useContentFilter.ts
export const useContentFilter = () => {
   const filter = useState<string>(() => '')

   const { items, pending } = useContent();
   const { data, pending, error, refresh } = useAsyncData(
      'filter',
      async () => await $fetch('http://localhost/api/filter', { query: items }),
   { watch: [items] }
   )
   filter.value = data.value ?? []

   return {
     filter,
     pending
   }
}
```

**Problem**
The problem is that 1 composable depends on the result of the other composable and I need to use await, because at this moment, we have null or undefined as the items. This is because it runs async without an await. I cannot make it await, because I use the useContentFilter in my page code like this:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const { filter, pending } = useContentFilter();
</script>
```

If I use await befoer useContentFilter(), then my page is not loading before all data has loaded, which is not what I want.

**OK endresult**
I want to be able to create async composables that can depend on each other and without blocking the page to load async. Any solutions?